# Mysql Query. Best way to get the query

Tags: mysql, sql

`field1|field2
 51301 | FOO
 51301 | FOO
 51302 | FOO
 51302 | BAR
 51302 | FOOBAR
 51302 | FOOBAR
 51303 | BAR
 51303 | BAR`

Field2 may contains FOO, BAR or FOOBAR. Mysql query to get all field1 if any point of time field2 had FOO and BAR and FOOBAR. In other words give me field1 if field2 has been set to FOO, BAR and FOOBAR. Order is not important.

`select field1 from mytable_audit group by id, field2 having field2 in ('FOO', 'BAR', 'FOOBAR');`

But it is getting results either field2 is either FOO, BAR or FOOBAR. Is there any way to get result if field2 is FOO and BAR and FOOBAR at some point of time.

Comment: I suggest you make an attempt, then show us what you tried and what specifically went wrong.

Comment: I did select field1 from mytable_audit group by id, field2 having field2 in ('FOO', 'BAR', 'FOOBAR');

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select field1
from table t
where field2 in ('FOO', 'FOOBAR', 'BAR')
group by field1
having count(distinct field2) = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to get a list of `field1` values that satisfy the specification:

```
SELECT t.field1
  FROM mytable t
 GROUP BY t.field1
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
         CASE WHEN t.field2 IN ('BAR','FOO','FOOBAR') 
              THEN t.field2 
              ELSE NULL
         END ORDER BY t.field2) = 'BAR,FOO,FOOBAR'
```